# /dev/sda1 /boot corrupted

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, fsck

I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 on an IBM-Thinkpad X61 tablet (no Windows dual boot) and it seems I have corrupted my `/dev/sda1 /boot`.

Symptoms:

1. When I login to home window, a "`System Program Problem`" detected prompt pops up twice, with two options: "`Report Problem`" or "`Cancel`".
2. If I don't press any button or press "Cancel" it automatically logs me off back to the login page.
3. When I press the "Report Problem", nothing happens and System monitor is showing `/dev/sda1 /boot` consuming 55% of my CPU resources

Prior to complete boot, when I go to the "`GNU GRUB`" (version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1) under <kbd>Advanced options for Ubuntu</kbd> → <kbd>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-34-generic recovery mode</kbd> under the <kbd>Recovery Menu</kbd> when I choose `fsck` to check all system files it gives me the following messages:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1 312/62248 files (18.3% non-contiguous), 135402/248832 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [769 terminated with status 1]
/dev/mapper/ubuntu/--vg-root: 264862 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 5621536/28211200 blocks
```

and then it freezes with the cursor blinking and no hard drive activity (waited 30 minutes).

Any technical advice including options on how to reinstall Ubuntu all together is greatly appreciated.  If my only option is to reinstall Ubuntu please keep in mind that I cannot change the BIOS to read the DVD first and so it automatically goes to boot the Ubuntu system installed on the hard drive.

Comment: can you post the output of `cat /var/log/fsck/checkfs` after you run fsck

Comment: @chicks: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/613067/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your edits in the future *even more*... **;-)**  (They're already good, but there are a few nifty things in there that you won't find in the help)

Comment: @Fabby: thanks for the suggestions.  I've been trying to use the `kbd` tag more often.  Kudos for listifying the symptoms.  I reread the [Markdown syntax](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for good measure.